# Kotlin cannot infer type of Function with method reference

Tags: generics, kotlin, types

why in the example below, with `mapTwo` Kotlin can't infer the type of `a` ?

```
fun <U> mapOne(f: (Int) -> U): U = TODO()
fun <U> mapTwo(f: Function<Int, U>): U = TODO()

fun <T> mapper(a: T): List<T> = TODO()

fun main() {
    mapOne(::mapper)
    mapTwo(::mapper) //won 't compile
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type inference is not the cause of a compilation error. `mapTwo<List<Int>>(::mapper)` will not compile either because of `::mapper` having the type `(T) -> List<T>` (`KFunction1<T, List<T>>`), which is not assignable to `Function<Int, U>`.